# Adding macro to run after posted data through 1st command

Tags: excel, vba

I have two commands button the first to post data and the second to run macro
how could I merge these two commands in one button?
as I need to post data then run macro

```
Private Sub post_Click()
    If Me.today.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox " You should enter contract date "
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not (Me.percentage.Value = "" Xor Me.txtamount.Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "You should select % or amount"
        Exit Sub
    End if 

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("6 Y")
    ws.Cells(3, 17).Value = ComboBox2.Text
    ws.Cells(4, 17).Value = Price.Text
    ws.Cells(6, 19).Value = today.Text
    ws.Cells(7, 24).Value = percentage.Text
    ws.Cells(7, 25).Value = txtamount.Text
    ws.Cells(1, 27).Value = ComboBoxpmtplan.Text
End Sub

Private Sub COMMRUN_Click()
    Macro1
End Sub
```

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer oooooh, this url is so bookmarked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call the function by name

```
Private Sub COMMRUN_Click()
    Macro1
    post_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Caveat: don't invoke event handler procedures directly - handlers mean to *handle events*, not to be invoked directly. The right thing to do is to extract the implementation out of the handler and invoke the logic from wherever it's needed. That said this answer is correct, and could be simplified to "exactly how you're invoking the `MsgBox` function from the standard type library: by typing up its name!"

Comment: not working , i need to post data after that run macro

Comment: what are the names of two functions and which function do you want to call afterwards?